# I don't why I cannot use finish activity when I use finish();

Tags: android, activity-finish

I don't why I cannot use finish activity when I use finish();

when the user click post button then I will send data to DB and finish activity.

But it is not working now.

[image]

this is my code

who knows what's happen?

```
private void uploadpostinfo(){
        String userID = getID;
        //String image = convertToString();
        String imageName = statusEdit.getText().toString();
        String sp2 = sp.getText().toString();
        String tag = tags.getText().toString();

        ApiInterface_Info apiInterface_info = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface_Info.class);
        Call<Img_Pojo_Info> call = apiInterface_info.uploadpostinfo(imageName,userID,sp2,tag);

        progressDialog.show();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Img_Pojo_Info>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Img_Pojo_Info> call, Response<Img_Pojo_Info> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Img_Pojo_Info img_pojo2 = response.body();
                //Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Post is Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(UploadActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(intent);
                UploadActivity.this.finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Img_Pojo_Info> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Server Response",""+t.toString());
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Are you on the same activity (UploadActivity in this case)? try calling finish() only

Comment: @ChanpreetSingh yes, it's same case, how do calling finish()? Do I should use onDestroy ?

Comment: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); Use this flag. remove finish activity code

Comment: I suggest printing log at the start of `onResponse` function to be sure it is actually called.

Comment: you should finish the activity before start a new one

Comment: @ChanpreetSingh it's same problem, cannnot close activity

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel half year ago, it was can working, but I don't know why it was not working now

Comment: @PhúcNguyễn It was a new Activity because that was open activity from fragment

Comment: I dont know what you mean but first, check if you can receive the response like @ShlomiKatriel said, then try my solution

Comment: @PhúcNguyễn So I need to add onResponse first?

Comment: that has already been there in you code, just add Log to see whether you receive the response

Comment: please don't add your code as an image, not everyone can access images

Comment: @a_local_nobody I add my code now

Comment: I found the where had problem, I didn't why call.enqueue(new Callback<Img_Pojo_Info>() wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tired to move finish() out of call.enqueue